# How to open IE popup to secondary screen, in FULLSCREEN mode

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

I need to implement the following feature and make it work in Internet Explorer:

- User clicks a link in the primary screen.
- A popup will be opened in the **secondary screen** and in **fullscreen** mode.

Some requirements:

- It must work in IE8 (and 9/10)
- For simplicity, we can assume that the secondary screen is located on the **right** of the primary screen. Also, the resolution of the secondary screen is known.
- Javascript is used, but VBScript would be also possible.

So far the prototype is working quite well

- the popup is opened with window.open with **left=screen.availWidth+1** -> will be opened in the secondary screen OK
- the fullscreen mode is activated with **Wscript.Shell sendKeys({F11})** trick. This has some random issues. Timing etc will make it fail sometimes.

There are couple of IE-specific problems that make the implementation much more difficult

- screen.availWidth returns always the primary screen resolution. E.g. Firefox returns the right size for popups located in secondary screen. Otherwise I could mimic the fullscreen mode by positioning the popup to fill the secondary screen completely.
- window.open() with "fullscreen=1" works too but it ALWAYS opens the popup in the primary screen. This happens even if I use timers to make it target to secondary screen. Also a temporary pop-up located in secondary screen does not help. Looks like the fs=1 will always open the window in the screen where the click originated.

And for clarity, this will be implemented for an intranet application and has valid and well justified reasons. There is no point to suggest to try another web browser.

Any ideas that has been proven to work are welcome!